# Npm install `vue@latest` error user agent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I wanted to try `staging.vuejs` https://staging.vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#with-build-tools
and it said that I only need to install it with command `npm init vue@latest` but I got this error :

[image: error message]

**SPEC**

Node : v12.13.0

@vue/cli : v4.5.15

Comment: have you googled process.env.npm_config_user_agent ??  are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error is because your Node version simply doesn't know what `??` means.

The `??` is a null coalescing operator. Looking at [the MDN docs for `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), you can see at the bottom that support for it was only added in Node 14.0. You're using Node v12.13.

There is really no other solution than to upgrade. I advice you to upgrade to the latest LTS version, which as of this writing is 16.